# css overflow-x:none not working

Tags: html, css, overflow

How can I prevent the content within horizontal `div` that overflows from showing?

I have this css:

```
#fixed_menu_div {
    width:200px;
    height:80%;
    float:left;
    left:0;
    overflow-x:none;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    position:fixed;
}
```

The `div` is displayed on the left of the page(s).

It is meant to hide the horizontal scrollbar:

```
overflow-x:none;
```

but its still showing. I want to keep the

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

and hide the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Try `overflow-x: hidden;`

Answer (score 5):

`none` in overflow ? I think this is not correct and I use net beans dont suggest me "none";

use one of this :

```
auto
hidden
no-content
no-display
scroll 
visible
```

for hide use `hidden` .
This tow reference for anyone need to study about overflow: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) and [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Comment: Can you add the reference to your answer for future readers? Also please use @ryangates in the comments so that I know you answered my question.